# PHP upload 512MB files library

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Is there a php backend library that allows a user to upload files upt to 512mb big and displays the progress in a bar through jquery / javascript?

Thanks,
EL

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+progress+bar

Comment: The max size of a file you can upload is controlled by `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` ini settings.

Comment: Can I specify the max_filesize for one script?

Answer (score 2):

I've used http://www.uploadify.com (the html5 version) and I've been happy with it.

Note that the upload size allowed depends on the php configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of tools available (just google it). If you want do do something your self you can check out this step-by-step guide

http://www.9lessons.info/2012/04/file-upload-progress-bar-with-jquery.html